# How to let Python 2.4.3 have the ability of extracting ZIP file that is introduced in Python 2.6?

Tags: python, zip

`ZipFile.extract(member[, path[, pwd]])` is a new functionality introduced in Python 2.6. For some reason I need to implement the ZipFile.extract in Python 2.4.3(2.4.3 cannot handle ZipFile but just some attributes).

I'm thinking of explicitly import [zipfile.py](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/6074530b526f/Lib/zipfile.py) in the python script in which I need to use the extract function.

My consideration is that I don't know if there is any new syntax or new functionality in the zipfile.py that is incompatible with the Python 2.4.3 standards.

Is there another approach for this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try it? Usually, you're better off just copying the new function(s) you want than replacing the entire module this way, but either way, it's easier to just test it and see if it works than to go online and ask other people to guess whether or not it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ZipFile.extract()` can be simulated by using `ZipFile.open()`, `open()`, and `shutil.copyfileobj()`. The functionality could even be monkey-patched into `ZipFile` based on the version of Python in use.

```
if PythonVersion < 2.6: # obviously not how it's done
  def myextract(self, member, path=None, pwd=None):
     ...
  zipfile.ZipFile.extract = myextract
```

Comment: +1. It's worth noting that the code for `Zipfile.extract` in 2.6 is pretty simple pure Python, and can be copied and pasted right out of the source that the OP linked to, without having to copy the entire file.